# How to guarantee Java collection

Tags: java, apache-commons

I would like to find an API like Apache Commons that will easily and always return a collection.

The intent is to produce code that doesn't require NPE checks or CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty checks prior to collection iteration.  The assumption in the code is to always guarantee a list instance thus eliminating code complexity for every collection iteration.

Here's an example of a method, but I would like an API instead of rolling my own.

```
private List<Account> emptyCollection(
        List<Account> requestedAccounts) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(requestedAccounts)) {
        return requestedAccounts;
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<Account>();
    }
}
```

I would like to find a generic API / method that could be used for any class generically.

Here are some of my research classes inside commons that may help me do the trick.
http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/TransformerUtils.html

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html

Maybe the .collect might work using a transformer.

I'm open to using alternative API's as well.

Comment: Alternative non-API solution: never return a null collection!

Comment: And what do you expect the library to do when there isn't any memory left?

Comment: @PaulTomblin Typically most coding that I've ever worked on, the Collection gets new'd up on the stack and then immediately gets put on the gc since it's not referenced.  Also, we don't internally hold onto the collections for a long time.  I think the issue is mute.  Although I'd prefer to move away from Java because it's a huge memory footprint hog in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this an example of what you mean?

```
public static <T> List<T> nullToEmpty(List<T> list) {
    if (list != null) {
        return list;
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Comment: Worth adding that Collections.emptyList is immutable so depending on the use it might make sense to return a `new xxxList`.

Comment: I went with your solution with assylias suggestion as well.  It's a small compromise until I found an external API that actually has this behavior.  Also, @Jesper used autoboxing which I wanted as well to eliminate the pesky warnings in Java.  Thanks all.  If you find an external API that has this out of box, please post.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, Do you simply want to avoid NPE, or also want to avoid CollectionUtil.isNotEmpty ?
The first is very easy, the second not so, because you essentially want to guarantee that your API will always return a Collection with at least one element.
That is a business centric constraint IMO, and not something you can guarantee via an API contract.

If all you want to avoid is NPE, you can use java.lang.Collections.EMPTY_(SET|MAP|LIST), classes. But mind you , these are immutable, i.e. the calling code, can't add objects to a collection returned this way. If you want the calling code to mutate the Collection (i.e. add/remove/update elements), then you'll have to return a zero element concrete implementation of your LIST|MAP|SET etc.